# Huawei push kit: Token returns empty on Huawei phone

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

I recently tried my app on a Huawei phone.

The problem is PushKit does not return a token and `getToken` result is empty.

In the log I get `GetTokenTask receive a empty token, please check HmsMessageService.onNewToken receive result.`, **but** there is not token given in `onNewToken` either.

Code to retrieve token:

```
GlobalScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        val appId = AGConnectServicesConfig.fromContext(this@MainActivity).getString("client/app_id")
        val token = HmsInstanceId.getInstance(this@MainActivity).getToken(appId, "HCM")
        Pulp.debug("Huawei", "Token received") {
            "token" to token
        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
        Pulp.error("Huawei", "Failed to fetch token", e) {
            "Cause" to (e.message ?: "Empty")
        }
    }
}
```

The result has not exception. But the token is empty (see last line of logs).

The code in the `HMSService`:

```
override fun onNewToken(token: String?) {
    super.onNewToken(token)
    Pulp.debug("Huawei", "(onNewToken): Huawei messaging token received") {
        "Token" to (token ?: "NO token")
    }
}
```

Full log from `auto_init` to the token request:

```
2020-09-16 15:33:50.791 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_AutoInit: Push init start
2020-09-16 15:33:50.854 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer: Builder->biInitFlag :false
2020-09-16 15:33:50.856 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer: Builder->biSetting :false
2020-09-16 15:33:50.859 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_CountryCodeBean: getCountryCode get country code from SIM_COUNTRY
2020-09-16 15:33:50.863 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest W/HMSSDK_CountryCodeBean: countryCode from system language is not reliable.
2020-09-16 15:33:50.864 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest E/HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer: Failed to get device issue country
2020-09-16 15:33:50.909 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: Succeed to find HMS apk: com.huawei.hwid version: 40100308
2020-09-16 15:33:50.934 19954-20000/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer: Builder->biInitFlag :false
2020-09-16 15:33:50.936 19954-20000/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer: Builder->biSetting :false
2020-09-16 15:33:50.936 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer: Builder->biInitFlag :false
2020-09-16 15:33:50.937 19954-20000/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_CountryCodeBean: getCountryCode get country code from SIM_COUNTRY
2020-09-16 15:33:50.938 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer: Builder->biSetting :false
2020-09-16 15:33:50.939 19954-20000/ir.malv.plusdependencytest W/HMSSDK_CountryCodeBean: countryCode from system language is not reliable.
2020-09-16 15:33:50.940 19954-20000/ir.malv.plusdependencytest E/HMSSDK_HMSBIInitializer: Failed to get device issue country
2020-09-16 15:33:50.953 19954-20000/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HiAnalyticsUtils: issueCountry initial
2020-09-16 15:33:50.953 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HiAnalyticsUtils: issueCountry initial
2020-09-16 15:33:50.954 19954-20000/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_CountryCodeBean: getCountryCode get country code from SIM_COUNTRY
2020-09-16 15:33:50.954 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_CountryCodeBean: getCountryCode get country code from SIM_COUNTRY
2020-09-16 15:33:50.956 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest W/HMSSDK_CountryCodeBean: countryCode from system language is not reliable.
2020-09-16 15:33:50.956 19954-20000/ir.malv.plusdependencytest W/HMSSDK_CountryCodeBean: countryCode from system language is not reliable.
2020-09-16 15:33:50.956 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HiAnalyticsUtils: not ChinaROM
2020-09-16 15:33:50.956 19954-20000/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HiAnalyticsUtils: not ChinaROM
2020-09-16 15:33:50.959 19954-20000/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HiAnalyticsUtils: hw_app_analytics_state value is 0
2020-09-16 15:33:50.959 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HiAnalyticsUtils: hw_app_analytics_state value is 0
2020-09-16 15:33:50.960 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HmsMessaging: invoke turnOnPush
2020-09-16 15:33:50.963 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HmsMessaging: turn on/off with AIDL
2020-09-16 15:33:50.970 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HuaweiApiManager: sendRequest
2020-09-16 15:33:50.971 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: ====== HMSSDK version: 50000301 ======
2020-09-16 15:33:50.972 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: Enter connect, Connection Status: 1
2020-09-16 15:33:50.973 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: connect minVersion:30000000
2020-09-16 15:33:50.975 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_Util: available exist: true
2020-09-16 15:33:50.976 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest E/HMSSDK_Util: In isAvailableLibExist, Failed to read meta data for the availableLoaded.
2020-09-16 15:33:50.977 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_Util: available exist: true
2020-09-16 15:33:50.981 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: current versionCode:40100308, minimum version requirements: 30000000
2020-09-16 15:33:50.986 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: check available result: 0
2020-09-16 15:33:50.987 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: enter bindCoreService
2020-09-16 15:33:51.007 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HuaweiApiManager: sendRequest
2020-09-16 15:33:51.008 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: ====== HMSSDK version: 50000301 ======
2020-09-16 15:33:51.009 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: Enter connect, Connection Status: 1
2020-09-16 15:33:51.010 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: connect minVersion:30000000
2020-09-16 15:33:51.010 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_Util: available exist: true
2020-09-16 15:33:51.013 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HMSPackageManager: current versionCode:40100308, minimum version requirements: 30000000
2020-09-16 15:33:51.016 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: check available result: 0
2020-09-16 15:33:51.017 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: enter bindCoreService
2020-09-16 15:33:51.681 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BinderAdapter: Enter onServiceConnected.
2020-09-16 15:33:51.682 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: Enter onServiceConnected.
2020-09-16 15:33:51.684 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BinderAdapter: Enter onServiceConnected.
2020-09-16 15:33:51.684 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: post msg api_name:push.setNotifyFlag, app_id:102760085|, pkg_name:ir.malv.plusdependencytest, sdk_version:50000301, session_id:*, transaction_id:102760085fyFlag20200916153350948378003, kitSdkVersion:50002300, apiLevel:1
2020-09-16 15:33:51.685 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseHmsClient: Enter onServiceConnected.
2020-09-16 15:33:51.689 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: in baseRequest + uri is :push.setNotifyFlag, transactionId is : 102760085fyFlag20200916153350948378003
2020-09-16 15:33:51.692 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: init uri:push.setNotifyFlag
2020-09-16 15:33:51.694 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: setResultCallback
2020-09-16 15:33:51.698 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: post msg api_name:push.gettoken, app_id:102760085|, pkg_name:ir.malv.plusdependencytest, sdk_version:50000301, session_id:*, transaction_id:102760085ttoken20200916153350948306787, kitSdkVersion:50002300, apiLevel:1
2020-09-16 15:33:51.706 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: in baseRequest + uri is :push.gettoken, transactionId is : 102760085ttoken20200916153350948306787
2020-09-16 15:33:51.708 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: init uri:push.gettoken
2020-09-16 15:33:51.709 19954-20004/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: setResultCallback
2020-09-16 15:33:51.720 19954-19972/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: setResult:0
2020-09-16 15:33:51.745 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: baseCallBack.onComplete
2020-09-16 15:33:51.746 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:0, error_code0, api_name:push.setNotifyFlag, app_id:102760085|, pkg_name:ir.malv.plusdependencytest, session_id:*, transaction_id:102760085fyFlag20200916153350948378003, resolution:null
2020-09-16 15:33:51.748 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseVoidTask: Operate succeed
2020-09-16 15:33:51.771 19954-19972/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_PendingResultImpl: setResult:0
2020-09-16 15:33:51.837 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: baseCallBack.onComplete
2020-09-16 15:33:51.839 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:0, error_code0, api_name:push.gettoken, app_id:102760085|, pkg_name:ir.malv.plusdependencytest, session_id:*, transaction_id:102760085ttoken20200916153350948306787, resolution:null
2020-09-16 15:33:51.842 19954-19954/ir.malv.plusdependencytest I/HMSSDK_HmsInstanceId: GetTokenTask receive a empty token, please check HmsMessageService.onNewToken receive result.
```

Logs with Tag=`pushlog`:

```
2020-09-16 20:15:10.585 7731-24998/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-84-859]enter set self show message control flag, req:{"enable":true,"packageName":"ir.malv.plusdependencytest"}(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.586 7731-24998/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-84-859]init uri:pushcore.enableNotify(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.586 7731-24998/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-84-859]await(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.586 7731-24998/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-84-859]awaitOnAnyThread timeout:10 unit:SECONDS(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.588 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]Request, URI: pushcore.enableNotify, clientId: {packageName: com.huawei.hwid, sdkVersion: 10000000, originPackageName: ir.malv.plusdependencytest, originAppId: 102760085, originHostAppId: 102760085, originSdkVersion: 50000301}
2020-09-16 20:15:10.588 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]enter enable notify request:EnableNotifyReq{packageName='ir.malv.plusdependencytest', enable=true}
2020-09-16 20:15:10.590 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]Response, uri: pushcore.enableNotify, statusCode: 0
2020-09-16 20:15:10.591 7731-24999/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-85-860]enter get token request:com.huawei.hms.support.api.entity.push.TokenReq{ pkgName: ir.malv.plusdependencytest isFirstTime: true scope: null appId: null} , transactionId:102760085ttoken20200916201509611018781(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.592 7731-19020/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Binder:7731_7-784]setResult:0(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.592 7731-24999/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-85-860]init uri:pushcore.gettoken(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.593 7731-24999/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-85-860]await(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.593 7731-24999/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-85-860]awaitOnAnyThread timeout:10 unit:SECONDS(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.595 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]Request, URI: pushcore.gettoken, clientId: {packageName: com.huawei.hwid, sdkVersion: 10000000, originPackageName: ir.malv.plusdependencytest, originAppId: 102760085, originHostAppId: 102760085, originSdkVersion: 50000301}
2020-09-16 20:15:10.595 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]GetTokenRequest: com.huawei.android.pushagent.core.support.entity.TokenReq{ pkgName: ir.malv.plusdependencytest},userId:0,transactionId:102760085ttoken20200916201509611018781
2020-09-16 20:15:10.596 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]check push connection is not exist, reconnect it.
2020-09-16 20:15:10.599 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]dispatchIntent over
2020-09-16 20:15:10.599 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]TRS exceed valid time, so need to query TRS again
2020-09-16 20:15:10.600 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]com.huawei.action.CONNECT_PUSHSRV alarm trigger, expectTriggerTime:0, current trigger time:1600271110600
2020-09-16 20:15:10.602 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]connect srv: TRS is invalid, so need to query TRS
2020-09-16 20:15:10.604 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:10.613 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:10.613 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]begin to get token from pushSrv, pkgName : ir.malv.plusdependencytest, userId :00
2020-09-16 20:15:10.617 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]apply token: TRS is invalid, so need to query TRS
2020-09-16 20:15:10.624 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:10.630 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]Response, uri: pushcore.gettoken, statusCode: 0
2020-09-16 20:15:10.632 7731-19020/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Binder:7731_7-784]setResult:0(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.636 7731-24999/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-85-860]request token for HMS from system push.(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.640 7731-14337/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Push-Task-1-717]request token for HMS by AIDL.(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.641 7731-14337/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Push-Task-1-717]init uri:pushcore.gettoken(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.642 7731-14337/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Push-Task-1-717]await(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.642 7731-14337/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Push-Task-1-717]awaitOnAnyThread timeout:10 unit:SECONDS(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:10.644 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]Request, URI: pushcore.gettoken, clientId: {packageName: com.huawei.hwid, sdkVersion: 10000000, originPackageName: ir.malv.plusdependencytest, originAppId: 102760085, originHostAppId: 102760085, originSdkVersion: 50000301}
2020-09-16 20:15:10.644 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]GetTokenRequest: com.huawei.android.pushagent.core.support.entity.TokenReq{ pkgName: com.huawei.hwid},userId:0,transactionId:102760085ttoken20200916201509611018781
2020-09-16 20:15:10.645 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]check push connection is not exist, reconnect it.
2020-09-16 20:15:10.647 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]dispatchIntent over
2020-09-16 20:15:10.647 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]TRS exceed valid time, so need to query TRS again
2020-09-16 20:15:10.648 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]com.huawei.action.CONNECT_PUSHSRV alarm trigger, expectTriggerTime:0, current trigger time:1600271110648
2020-09-16 20:15:10.653 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]connect srv: TRS is invalid, so need to query TRS
2020-09-16 20:15:10.657 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:10.657 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:10.664 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]begin to get token from pushSrv, pkgName : com.huawei.hwid, userId :00
2020-09-16 20:15:10.667 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]apply token: TRS is invalid, so need to query TRS
    Tags: [Huawei]
    Message: Succefully turned on Push
2020-09-16 20:15:10.675 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:10.678 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]Response, uri: pushcore.gettoken, statusCode: 0
2020-09-16 20:15:10.679 7731-8371/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Binder:7731_6-640]setResult:0(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:23.427 7731-25033/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-86-862]enter get token request:com.huawei.hms.support.api.entity.push.TokenReq{ pkgName: ir.malv.plusdependencytest isFirstTime: false scope: null appId: null} , transactionId:102760085ttoken20200916201523364702182(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:23.428 7731-25033/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-86-862]init uri:pushcore.gettoken(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:23.429 7731-25033/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-86-862]await(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:23.429 7731-25033/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-86-862]awaitOnAnyThread timeout:10 unit:SECONDS(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:23.432 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]Request, URI: pushcore.gettoken, clientId: {packageName: com.huawei.hwid, sdkVersion: 10000000, originPackageName: ir.malv.plusdependencytest, originAppId: 102760085, originHostAppId: 102760085, originSdkVersion: 50000301}
2020-09-16 20:15:23.433 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]GetTokenRequest: com.huawei.android.pushagent.core.support.entity.TokenReq{ pkgName: ir.malv.plusdependencytest},userId:0,transactionId:102760085ttoken20200916201523364702182
2020-09-16 20:15:23.433 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]check push connection is not exist, reconnect it.
2020-09-16 20:15:23.436 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]dispatchIntent over
2020-09-16 20:15:23.436 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]TRS exceed valid time, so need to query TRS again
2020-09-16 20:15:23.437 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]com.huawei.action.CONNECT_PUSHSRV alarm trigger, expectTriggerTime:0, current trigger time:1600271123437
2020-09-16 20:15:23.439 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]connect srv: TRS is invalid, so need to query TRS
2020-09-16 20:15:23.443 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:23.444 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:23.449 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]begin to get token from pushSrv, pkgName : ir.malv.plusdependencytest, userId :00
2020-09-16 20:15:23.453 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]apply token: TRS is invalid, so need to query TRS
2020-09-16 20:15:23.458 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:23.462 6359-25001/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-35-1642]Response, uri: pushcore.gettoken, statusCode: 0
2020-09-16 20:15:23.462 7731-8371/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Binder:7731_6-640]setResult:0(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:23.465 7731-25033/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Core-GWTask-86-862]request token for HMS from system push.(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:23.465 7731-14337/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Push-Task-1-717]request token for HMS by AIDL.(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:23.466 7731-14337/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Push-Task-1-717]init uri:pushcore.gettoken(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:23.466 7731-14337/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Push-Task-1-717]await(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:23.466 7731-14337/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Push-Task-1-717]awaitOnAnyThread timeout:10 unit:SECONDS(:289)
2020-09-16 20:15:23.469 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]Request, URI: pushcore.gettoken, clientId: {packageName: com.huawei.hwid, sdkVersion: 10000000, originPackageName: ir.malv.plusdependencytest, originAppId: 102760085, originHostAppId: 102760085, originSdkVersion: 50000301}
2020-09-16 20:15:23.470 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]GetTokenRequest: com.huawei.android.pushagent.core.support.entity.TokenReq{ pkgName: com.huawei.hwid},userId:0,transactionId:102760085ttoken20200916201523364702182
2020-09-16 20:15:23.471 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]check push connection is not exist, reconnect it.
2020-09-16 20:15:23.474 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]dispatchIntent over
2020-09-16 20:15:23.474 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]TRS exceed valid time, so need to query TRS again
2020-09-16 20:15:23.476 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]com.huawei.action.CONNECT_PUSHSRV alarm trigger, expectTriggerTime:0, current trigger time:1600271123476
2020-09-16 20:15:23.480 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:23.481 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]connect srv: TRS is invalid, so need to query TRS
2020-09-16 20:15:23.487 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]begin to get token from pushSrv, pkgName : com.huawei.hwid, userId :00
2020-09-16 20:15:23.491 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]apply token: TRS is invalid, so need to query TRS
2020-09-16 20:15:23.492 6359-6417/? I/PushLog100101302: [ReceiverDispatcher-383]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:23.500 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1
2020-09-16 20:15:23.503 6359-25003/? I/PushLog100101302: [IO-pool-thread-36-1644]Response, uri: pushcore.gettoken, statusCode: 0
2020-09-16 20:15:23.504 7731-8371/? I/PushLog40100308_HMS: [Binder:7731_6-640]setResult:0(:289)
```

---

Information about phone and app:

- Phone: **Huawei Y7p**
- Android: **10**
- EMUI: **10.1.0**
- AGConnect: `'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.1.300'`
- PushKit: `"com.huawei.hms:push:5.0.2.300"`
- AGConnect-Core: `"com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.4.1.300"`
- Auto init:

```
<meta-data
     android:name="push_kit_auto_init_enabled"
     android:value="true" />
```

- HMS service:

```xml
<service
    android:name=".services.HmsService"
    android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.huawei.push.action.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

---

Some misc informations:

- Same app **CAN** obtain HMS token on a **Samsung G-A40** with **HMS Core** `v5.0.0.304`
- No account synced with App Gallery and device is brand new
- Region (Country and IP): **Iran**

---

Extra informations requested:

- Galaxy A40 logs from 0 to sending uplink [[Link]](https://gist.github.com/mahdi-malv/b91e3913130bbd7ff651f8aa048ff710)
- Galaxy A40 logs with `Phone` permission allowed for HMS core [Link](https://gist.github.com/mahdi-malv/39d88c20e16860f771d0d93f8623b207)

Comment: Hey there! Just checking, did you implement the same getToken() method as in https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-client-dev-0000001050042041-V5 ? If yes, can you please comment out push_kit_auto_init_enabled from your AndroidManifest.xml and try again?

Comment: @clho I updated the question with the code I've tried for obtaining token. I removed the application data and retried without the `auto_init` tag. But still token is received empty.

Comment: I have tried your getToken method, and it worked for me. Can you also show your onNewToken method? (Also, just want to make sure, have you enabled push kit service on AppGallery Connect?)

Comment: @clho Done. However. It's not even called. Meanwhile I'm able to fetch the token in a non-huawei HMS-Core included phone.

Comment: If it's not even called, are you sure the service class path in your manifest ".services.HmsService" is the correct path to your OnNewToken method?

Comment: Of course. As I said, I run the app on both non-huawei and huawei phones simultaneously. So this can not be the case.

Comment: Can you collect some log with TAG "pushlog" when getting token? And also show the version of the Push service. (Note: way to find push service versionSettings -> apps -> apps -> Click 'show system processes' in the upper right corner -> search 'push service' )

Comment: I have the same exact problem in my application running on huawei P30 Pro.

Comment: `Push service` version is `10.1.0.303`. Will send you the logs asap

Comment: @bigface I've added `pushlog` logs to the question details. However, there's a line in these logs which seems interesting. "`Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26, belong id is -1, server ip is , region of TRS server is -1`. My region is **Iran**. Does this mean push does not work here? AFAIK, this should not happen. SINCE my non-huawei phone does receive push messages with Iran IP.

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv Please provide the log from Samsung G-A40. :)

Comment: @shirley The logs is provided at the end of question (Extra informations) and also acceissble via [this link](https://gist.github.com/mahdi-malv/b91e3913130bbd7ff651f8aa048ff710)

Answer (score 2):

Mixing the automatic `push_kit_auto_init_enabled` and manual retrieval methods `getToken()` together will result into problems.

We had a similar issue where tokens sometimes are received and other times they weren't. It seemed very random but as a basic rule you should either use one of the automatic methods described [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-client-dev-0000001050042041#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050042041__section13546121751811) or you stick to [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-client-dev-0000001050042041#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050042041__section876955375919) section which describes how to apply for a token as soon as you finished all the configurations ([part 1](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-config-agc-0000001050170137), [part 2](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-integrating-sdk-0000001050040084), [part 3](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-cfg-manifest-0000001050042037) and [part 4](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-config-obfuscation-scripts-0000001050176973)).

That should solve the issue for anyone else having this issue in a country where push messages are allowed.

Comment: I'm afraid I could not resolve it considering your solution. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Yes, I read that it is probably related to you country not supporting the push kit yet but in case anyone stumbles upon that issue and your Stackoverflow question, he/she won't have to try out all the different things we did in order to figure out a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Push Kit is not [supported in Iran currently](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/support-regions-0000001050047520).
2. Please check whether the SIM card is insert to your Samsung Galaxy A40. Push Kit will determine your service area by condition. If you can, please report the MCC/MNC of the SIM card and the area of the network for initially using Push Kit. Based on the logs, the service area of Samsung Galaxy A40 is Europe. Therefore, you can obtain a token.

To solve the failure in obtaining a token by @ [Angelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1482726/angelo), proceed as follows:

You can get a pushToken on the premise that the preparation work has been done, especially enabling the push service and setting up the fingerprint. For details, refer to the following link: [App development](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/Preparations).

You can view the logcat with filter "hmssdk" after checking. If there is an exception, you can see the error code, and then you can refer to [the document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/push-ErrorEnum4) for how to solve the problem.

Show the log if possible so that we can solve the problem together.

For more details, you can refer to the document about [how to get pushToken](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/push-basic-capability#h2-1576218800370).

If the EMUI version is 10.0 or later on a Huawei device, a token will be returned through the getToken method. If the getToken method fails to be called, HUAWEI Push Kit automatically caches the token request and calls the method again. A token will then be returned through the onNewToken method. If the EMUI version on a Huawei device is earlier than 10.0 and no token is returned using the getToken method, a token will be returned using the onNewToken method.

Comment: I'm afraid the link attached to the term "not supported in Iran" does not refer to support of users receiving push. Because this results users without ability to receive push notifications at all. When creating app, I selected the region as Europe to specify the server location (Since Iran was not in the list, I gave up the fast response and selected the closest region). Also, my A40 phone has the same location and features an Iranian SIM card, same as the Huawei phone. I believe the issue is not lack of support. BTW, What does `get grs failed, the errorcode is -5` mean? No desc about `-5`

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv All right. Could you please provide the following information for further analysis? 
1. Check whether give **Read Phone** permission in HMS Core on your Samsung mobile phone.
2. Obtain the IP address of your Samsung mobile phone (access the website: https://whatismyipaddress.com/).
3. Please uninstall the HMS Core and reinstall the app on the Samsung mobile phone, to check whether the token can be obtained. If yes, send me the token.

Comment: IP is Iran for sure. But you mentioned `Phone` permission. I checked the samsung device and **No permission was allowed**. It does not work since I re-installed the HMS core (Token will not be given and thread will wait. Remember my other question?). I also get `get grs failed, the errorcode is -5` error (I also noticed `-3` as well in log). I'll be happy to know what is wrong.

Comment: can you share the whole log when getting token in this case? (It does not work since I re-installed the HMS core)

Comment: @bigface Here you can see the logs: [log gist](https://gist.github.com/mahdi-malv/39d88c20e16860f771d0d93f8623b207)

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv is this log from A40 or Huawei Y7p? Also you can share the log with TAG "pushlog" and your HMS Core version.

Comment: @bigface Recent discussions was about Samsung A40. Which one satisfices your needs?

Comment: yes, I also mean Samsung A40. Can you share the log with TAG "pushlog" and your HMS Core version?

Comment: @bigface [Here](https://gist.github.com/mahdi-malv/39d88c20e16860f771d0d93f8623b207) is the updated log. HMSCore (`v5.0.2.300`).   Checking PushLog tags gives a valid line saying `Not allow to use push in this area, and not pass interval,result code: 26`. Does it mean The "Pushkit not supported in Iran" is true?

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv yes, you are right, just as shirley said. Push Kit is not supported in Iran currently, https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/support-regions-0000001050047520

Comment: @shirley You might want to update the answer. Since Iran has  been added to supported regions AFAIK. Currently token gets returned for Iran IP.

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv Great. While it has not been added on [the documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-Guides-V5/support-regions-0000001050047520-V5) yet. :)